# Is It Fine to Use A 3.5" HD In An Enclosure as an External Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, external-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are all hard disks suitable for external enclosure?](https://superuser.com/questions/97039/are-all-hard-disks-suitable-for-external-enclosure)

Is it fine to use a 3.5" hard drive (For example, a WD Caviar Green) inside an enclosure as an external hard drive?

Would there be too much heat produced that the hard drive would fry?

Also, would it be safe to put a 7200 RPM 3.5" drive (For example, WD Caviar Black) within an enclosure? Would the drive spin too much to produce too much heat or vibrate too much (7200) that it would spin itself to death?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it too much. That's what enclosures are meant for. Just don't keep your enclosure underneath a heat lamp and you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes, but would 7200" be too vicious for the drive itself? Enclosures don't have fans, unlike desktops though.

Comment: I wouldn't put in a 10k, but a 7200 RPM should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some 3.5 enclosures do have a fan, this will increase the life of any drive you put in it.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182210

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007705%20600006254%20600006272&IsNodeId=1&name=SATA%20I/II

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=3.5+external+enclosure+fan+usb&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=C_H3TkwpwTKzaCpHCNqmy-dYPAAAAqgQFT9CwswY&fp=7db4f7af4a13aa89